# SMS delivery on 4.4 kitkat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

If I delete a message with a single tick, does it just get deleted from my local device, or does it stop the message from being delivered to the recipient?

I posted a message in a group and it just shows a single tick. I don't want a particular person in that group to see the message.

Answer (score 0):

If the message has a single tick it means the message is **sent** and it's waiting to be seen by the user.

When the message has been seen by the user, the message will show a **double tick**.

**For example :** WhatsApp & Viber